# Is this beneficial to use aspnetdb database while creating a website?

Tags: aspnetdb

I am creating a new website , and while doing so i am little bit confused with Aspnetdb database , this contains ready made features for authorization and authentication checks , So should i use this database for user controls? Is there any disadvantage?

Answer (score 0):

you can use built in Aspnetdb database for website it will surely not going to harm your website.And also it depends on type of website you are building if website has very high number of visitors or member creating your own database is more beneficial in terms functionality and scalability.